# Make a variable available in application scope in railway js

Tags: javascript, node.js, railway.js

I'm using railwayjs for my new project, which uses passport framework for authentication. In the `environment.js` file, i'm `require`ing and configuring the passport details. I've a controller `auth` which does the login. So inside an action in auth controller i need to access the same passport variable i've used in `environment.js`. how do i do that? am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create a global, though, railwayjs specific alternative may exist.

```
// environment.js
global.Auth = {user: "123"};


// Another file;
console.log(Auth); // {user: "123};
```